# Search Doesn't Display Results Until I Click "Search My Stuff"

Tags: dropbox, windows-10

In Windows 7, when I would click the Start button and then start typing a search term, it would start displaying the corresponding search results.

On my 2 Windows 10 machines that were upgraded, it will only show results from items in my Documents folder, Desktop, etc but not items in my Dropbox which is at c:\Dropbox even though I added it to the search index and the computer has finished indexing.

I know the files are in the search index because if I click "Search My Stuff" it will then show the correct results including the items in the Dropbox folder.

It isn't a big deal but it is a little annoying having to go an extra step every time I search for a document.

I get the same behavior when clicking the Search/Cortana icon also.
Any ideas?  Does it only include items there that are in your Users/username directory?

Comment: Having several problems along these lines, I posted [this feature suggestion](https://windows.uservoice.com/forums/265757-windows-feature-suggestions/suggestions/9252939-search-everywhere-interface).

Comment: Actually this is a big deal and the main reason for me that Win10/8.1/8 is worse than Win7. Start10/STart8 restores the old search, but I'd much rather not have the add-on. Why did they ruin search? Why do I have to click "My Stuff" after typing the search term to have it search my stuff? Crazy.

Answer (score 0):

A temporar solution is using the freeware [Classic Shell](http://www.classicshell.net/). That way you get a windows 7 styled start menu and the search will show ALL results (no need to click on "Search my Stuff").